# XML to SQL Server table/column returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an XML stored in this format. When I use the below code it only returns NULL. Is there anything I am missing here?? Thanks in advance.

```
Declare @xmlData xml;
set @xmlData =
'<ProcessTask ProcessFile="Process1" TaskID="MyTsk" URL="www.google.com">
   <LinkParams UserId="007"  CountryId="1" Email="james.bond@gmail.com;" EmailSubject="New Mission" EndDate="2022-01-01" />
</ProcessTask>'

SELECT 
    n.value('(./UserId/text())[1]','int') as ArchiveUserId
 , n.value('(./Email/text())[1]','Varchar(500)') as Email
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ProcessTask/LinkParams') as a(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required data is in attributes. That's why `.value()` method's XPath expressions should reflect it.

**SQL**

```
Declare @xmlData XML =
N'<ProcessTask ProcessFile="Process1" TaskID="MyTsk" URL="www.google.com">
    <LinkParams UserId="007" CountryId="1" Email="james.bond@gmail.com;"
                EmailSubject="New Mission" EndDate="2022-01-01"/>
</ProcessTask>';

SELECT n.value('@UserId','INT') as ArchiveUserId
    , n.value('@Email','VARCHAR(500)') as Email
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ProcessTask/LinkParams') as a(n);
```

**Output**

```
+---------------+-----------------------+
| ArchiveUserId |         Email         |
+---------------+-----------------------+
|             7 | james.bond@gmail.com; |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: @DeepenRajDawadi, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.